# MonoGame not all letters being drawn with DrawString

Tags: xna, c#, graphics, monogame

I'm currently making a dynamic user interface for my game and are setting up having text on my buttons. I'm having an odd issue where, when i use a specific piece of code to determine the text position, it will not render all of the text passed to `DrawString`. Even weirder, is if i insert another `DrawString` after this, drawing more text at a different place, different parts of the text will be drawn.

The code for drawing my button with the text attached is:

```
public override void Draw(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt)
{
    sb.Draw(currentImage, GetRelativeRectangle(), Color.White);
    sb.DrawString(font, text, 
        new Vector2(this.GetRelativeDrawOffset().X + this.Width / 2 - font.MeasureString(text).X / 2,
            this.GetRelativeDrawOffset().Y + this.Height / 2 - font.MeasureString(text).Y / 2), textColor);
}
```

The methods in the creation of the `Vector2` simply get the draw position of the button. I'm then doing some calculation to center the text.

This produces this when the text is set to 'Test':

[image]

And when i enter this piece of code below the first `DrawString`:

```
sb.DrawString(font, "test", new Vector2(500, 50), Color.Pink);
```

[image]

I should mention that that grey square is being drawn in the same `spritebatch`, before the button and the text.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I have a feeling it may be due to draw order, but i have no idea how to control that.

Comment: try drawing the text on another `spritebatch` `begin-end` block just after the grey box. It is probably having Z-Ordering issues.

Comment: Is this one thing I can resolve without using more than one sprite batch? I'd have to refractor some code in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `SpriteBatch` is doing some layer ordering behind the scenes that is not likely what you want.
You have three ways to fix this, choose what fits you best:

- Separate this rect and the text batches.

Example:

```
batch.begin(/*...*/);
batch.draw(/*rectangle*/);
batch.end();
batch.begin(/*...*/);
batch.drawString(/*text*/);
batch.end();
```

- Use the [`layerDepth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx) argument to organize it. This should be the preferred method, since you can combine rendering any way you want to organize things.

Example:

```
batch.begin(/*...*/);
batch.draw(/*rectangle*/, 1.0f); //1 is the backlayer
batch.drawString(/*text*/, 0.0f); //0 is the front layer
batch.end();
```

You can make windows sit at 1.0f, buttons at 0.9f, button outlines at 0.85f, text at 0.7f... any combination should work.

- On [`spriteBatch.begin()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433698.aspx), set the SpriteSortMode to BackToFront or Texture. Everything should be drawn in the order you call the draws.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i think the best solution for my purposes would be the first solution. I can then separate my `Draw()` function into 3 - `DrawBackground`, `DrawMiddleground` and `DrawForeground`. This should provide sufficient dept for my controls. I'll mark it as the answer if it works when i get home!